# Jenkins partial output displaying password for Ansible Git

Tags: git, jenkins, ansible

I have use withcredentials as well as ansible vault. However, when there is a failure it is showing the password. Below are the error showing password.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin 'http://****:********@112.29.49.90:8080/Code/my_repo.git' /home/jenkins/jenkins_project/ansible/roles/roles_name/git_repo_file", "msg": "fatal: unable to access 'http://****:********@112.29.49.90:8080/Code/my_repo.git': Empty reply from server", "rc": 128, "stderr": "fatal: unable to access 'http://****:mypassword%40@112.29.49.90:8080/Code/my_repo.git': Empty reply from server\n", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: unable to access 'http://****:mypassword%40@112.29.49.90:8080/Code/my_repo.git': Empty reply from server"], "stdout": "Cloning into '/home/jenkins/jenkins_project/ansible/roles/roles_name/git_repo_file'...\n", "stdout_lines": ["Cloning into '/home/jenkins/jenkins_project/ansible/roles/roles_name/git_repo_file'..."]}
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#keep-secret-data

Answer (score 0):

To hide credentails in output just install mask passwords plugin.

Comment: hi actually i passing this value from jenkins. and in jenkins already beens masked

Comment: can i know why partial output is nmasked other output not masked?

Comment: because of ":" special symbol. mask passwords plugin will mask username and password.

Comment: hi can i know why then other 2 it was masked

Comment: Can't answer this question.